# Create a copy of every page with a watermark

Tags: watermark

I often print letters with latex and I want to print every letter twice : once normal and once with a watermark ('COPY').

Is there any way to produce a single pdf file containing twice the letter, once with and once without the watermark as described ?

Until now, I did write the document in a file, say foo.tex and then imported it twice but it is not a good procedure (for reverse search for example)

```
\import{foo}
\newpage
\import{foo} --with some command for a watermark--
```

Comment: do you need the copies collating (possible but less convenient) or can you print out both 1st pages then both 2nd pages etc (easier)

Comment: It is no problem if it is not collated. In practice, the (not duplicated) document will consist of 1 page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{letter}
\newbox\shbox
\usepackage{graphicx,color}

\let\oldshipout\shipout
\def\shipout\vbox#1{%
\global\setbox\shbox\vbox{#1}%
\oldshipout\copy\shbox
\oldshipout\hbox{%
\rlap{\scalebox{25}{\rotatebox{50}{\color{red}Draft}}}%
\box\shbox}%
}
\begin{document}

\address{here\\or\\there}
\signature{me}

\begin{letter}{Someone}
\opening{Dear sir,}

\def\a{Stuff goes here. Stuff goes here. Stuff goes here. }
\def\b{1: \a\a 2: \a\a 3: \a\a 4: \a 5: \a\a 6: \a 7: \a}

\b\b

Red Green Blue: \b\ Yellow \b\b

One two three four \b.

\closing{The End}
\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What happens if the page contains hyperlinks? My guess is that it will lead to pdftex duplicate hyperlink warnings.

Comment: @Aditya yes, but the question said print letter, so I assume it's aimed at a dead tree not the internet.

Comment: Nice solution ! Do you know how to center the watermark ?

Comment: @user81566  visual centre probably takes a bit of adjustment anyway so easiest is to replace `\rlap{...}` by `\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(10,20){\scalebox...}\end{picture}`  then you can tune the `(10,20)` to put it anywhere on the page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! Perfect and simple solution, just needed to read about boxes to figure it out. I just used `tikz` nodes to do the watermark with opacity.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one option using the [`pdfpages`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) and [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background) packages; your `original.tex` file looks something like

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[some,contents=Copy]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\signature{Your name}
\address{Street \\ City \\ Country}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
\lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
\closing{Yours Faithfully,}
\ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
\encl{Enclosures.}
\end{letter}

\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\BgThispage\pagestyle{empty}},noautoscale]{copy.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I used the `letter` document class, but you can use any other of the more versatile classes around.

You first process the document commenting out the line:

```
\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\BgThispage\pagestyle{empty}},noautoscale]{copy.pdf}
```

Then you copy the resulting PDF file to copy.pdf using (on Linux):

```
cp original.pdf copy.pdf
```

Then you uncomment out the line

```
\includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\BgThispage\pagestyle{empty}},noautoscale]{copy.pdf}
```

And reprocess `original.tex`.

An image of the result for the above example:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is same as Gonzalo's, but some work reduced and every thing in one file as source.

Your actual letter is contained inside `\begin{filecontents*}` and `\end{filecontents*}`

```
%% compile this with --shell-escape option enabled. i.e., pdflatex --shell-escape mainletter
%%-----mainletter.tex-----
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[some,contents=Copy]{background}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{filecontents*}{letter.tex}                              %% actual letter starts
  %
  \documentclass{letter}
  \usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just for the example
  %\usepackage[some,contents=Copy]{background}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  %
  \signature{Your name}
  \address{Street \\ City \\ Country}
  %
  \pagestyle{empty}
  %
  \begin{document}
  %
  \begin{letter}{Company name \\ Street\\ City\\ Country}
  \opening{Dear Sir or Madam:}
  \lipsum[4]\lipsum[4]
  \closing{Yours Faithfully,}
  \ps{P.S. Here goes your ps.}
  \encl{Enclosures.}
  \end{letter}
  \end{document}
  %  
  \end{filecontents*}                             %% actual letter ends
%
\immediate\write18{pdflatex letter}
%
\begin{document}
  %% comment first line if you want if you want two pdf file-- letter.pdf and mainletter.pdf. If you want them collated, then don't comment.
  \includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\pagestyle{empty}},noautoscale]{letter.pdf}
  \includepdf[pages={-},pagecommand={\BgThispage\pagestyle{empty}},noautoscale]{letter.pdf}
\end{document}
```

This will give you two pdf files - `letter.pdf` and `mainletter.pdf`. `letter.pdf` is your letter and `mainletter.pdf` will contain the copy with watermark, if you comment out the first line (as indicated in code). If you want them collated, then both lines may be left as such.

[image]