# Text over page (including text and floating object)

Tags: watermark

I'd like to add  an oblique label: typically it would be a large gray banner that  says "Accepted".  I want it on each page and over any other "objects" including text, table, figures, anything. Ideally, because I'm travelling, I do not have the TeX source of the PDF, so my idea was to create a `.tex` which includes the manuscript (in PDF) over multiple pages and then add the oblique banner all over it. 
Is this something doable with LaTeX?

Comment: There are multiple examples tagged as [tag:watermark]. For example, see [Add watermark that overlays the images](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/118939/5764); [Transparent foreground watermark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132582/5764); [Create a copy of every page with a watermark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/130994/5764)

Comment: Oh, yeah "watermark" is the keyword I was actually looking for. Great thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For those who might be interested in this "issue", following an example of "watermark" use (to add in the preambule of your .tex file):

```
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{Pre-print accepted for publication}
\SetWatermarkScale{1.2}
```